# How to use Iris color picker on front-end?

Tags: theme-development

I am trying to use new Iris color picker on the front-end. I succeed in using it on back-end: while using it on theme options I just enqueued the color picker like this …

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
```

… and hooked it to `admin_enqueue_scripts`. It worked.

However, I don't think the same process will work on the front-end by just hooking to `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Should I have to include the core file of new Iris color picker myself, or there is some way I can enqueue the color picker from front-end as I have done in my theme option code?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-implement-the-wordpress-iris-picker-into-my-plugin-on-the-front-end

Comment: Check out [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/25809/color-picker-widget.php). It is an an example widget using the Iris color picker

Answer (score -3):

you can copy js and css files into your plugin path or theme path, then register and load them with other handles.

Comment: Why re-invert the wheel? WordPress includes those scripts in core for a reason

Comment: Yes, WordPress includes those scripts in core and I enqueued those file in my back-end and used in my theme option but while enqueueing it in front-end, it didn't work