# Using Iris Colorpicker on TinyMCE shortcodes page

Tags: plugins, tinymce, color-picker

I'm actually working on a small shortcodes plugin.

On plugin main file I register TinyMCE button and link core js about button:

```
add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "shortcodes_tinymce_plugin");
add_filter("mce_buttons", "register_shortcodes_button");

function register_shortcodes_button($buttons) {
    array_push($buttons, "separator", "shortcodes");
    return $buttons;
}

function shortcodes_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array) {
    $plugin_array['shortcodes'] = PLUGINDIR_URI . 'tiny_mce_script.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
```

Which contains this code:

```
(function() {  

 tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.shortcodes', {

    init : function(ed, url) {              

        ed.addButton('shortcodes', {  
            title : 'Utilizer shortcodes',  
            image : url.replace('/js','')+'/img/shortcodes.png',  
            cmd : 'shortcodes',
            pluginurl : ajaxurl                
        });

        ed.addCommand('shortcodes', function() {
            ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url.replace('/js','')+'../../tinymce_shortcode.php',
                width : 510 + parseInt(ed.getLang('button.delta_width', 0)),
                height : 415 + parseInt(ed.getLang('button.delta_height', 0)),
                inline : 1
            }, {
                plugin_url : url
            });
        });

    }

 });

 tinymce.PluginManager.add('shortcodes', tinymce.plugins.shortcodes);
 }
)();
```

When you click the button modal page loads this file tinymce_shortcode.php
which contains this content on top of document:

```
<?php 

require_once("../../../../wp-load.php"); 

if ( !current_user_can('publish_posts') ) exit();

wp_register_script( 'shortcodes',   PLUGINDIR_URI . "shortcodes.js", false, "1.0", true );   
wp_register_script( 'tiny-mce-popup',   PLUGINDIR_URI . "tiny_mce_popup.js", false, "1.0", true );   

wp_enqueue_script( 
    array( 
        'iris', 
        'json2', 
        'jquery', 
        'jquery-ui-core', 
        'jquery-ui-sortable',
        'jquery-ui-tabs',
        'jquery-ui-slider',
        'jquery-ui-datepicker',
        'jquery-ui-autocomplete',
        'tiny-mce-popup',
        'shortcodes',
        'media-upload', 
        'thickbox',
    )  
); ?>
```

Then on bottom right before body gets closed I execute this code:

```
<?php do_action('admin_print_scripts'); ?>
<?php do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts'); ?>
```

All of javascript libraries are loaded like jquery, jquery-ui, media-upload, thickbox, jso2 etc. Only iris the color picker ones do not get loaded. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your actual code, not only what error output your get.

Comment: `require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");` <-- there has got to be a better way!

Comment: @kaiser my main problem here is to load iris color picker, and the code to load iris is up there.

Comment: @GhostToast do you have any better idea ?

Comment: Please show what you currently got...

Comment: Hi @kaiser I got all scripts loaded like `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-includes/js/json2.min.js?ver=2011-02-23'></script>` except colorpicker. So when I do wp_enqueue_script('iris'); can't get result of `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wp-includes/js/iris.js?ver=2011-02-23'></script>`

Comment: First, please use [edit] to add further info. Second, please show us what you code, not only what result or problem that generates.

Comment: Hi @kaiser I know how to use edit, thanks anyway. About code I think this is all what I should paste here, otherwise the question will get long and worst, meaning miss understandable.

Comment: Please, just use the [edit] ... so far _no one_ understands what you're doing and why you're doing that. Else it will get closed.

Comment: Hi @kaiser I just edited it tell me if its ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably is the following line in your JavaScript file:

```
file : url.replace('/js','')+'../../tinymce_shortcode.php'
```

First, this way you're bringing it out of context. Just load it up front when you init the plugin (and when you're on a `post.php` or `post-new.php` request - see `current_screen()` return values to narrow that down to the needed requests where you want to load your plugin).

The TinyMCE [windowManager](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api3%3aclass.tinymce.windowmanager) isn't meant to load PHP files. It *can* load HTML files to outsource *the needed MarkUp*/the view. Nothing more. If you need to generate MarkUp server side, simply build it inside a function or method and push the result to your JS file by localizing this values (more about it in the next paragraph). Then use either `.confirm()` or `.open()` depending on your task.

Next, you're `replace`-ing URis. That makes it highly dependent on the actual file location. Remember that the plugin directory can be moved. And that additional plugin directories can be [added next to the original one](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/WP-Plugin-Directories). Simply don't do that. If you need a relative URL in a JavaScript file, simply use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and `plugins_url( __FILE__, "your-file.php" )` and `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."your-file.php"`. Not that you'd need that in this case.

Last, ***never ever*** go and load stuff outside the WP context if you aren't loading it outside of WP at all. In short: If you need to load `wp-load.php` - and therefore the whole WP core - you're doing something pretty wrong.

Comment: Based on your answer I will have to change the concept to stick with wp core and not load it externally. However the solution that I found to this problem was this and worked pretty well.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-implement-the-wordpress-iris-picker-into-my-plugin-on-the-front-end

Comment: For the next time, please use the search _before_ asking the question :P

Comment: I did but couldn't figure out what I was doing, thanks a lot for your time and effort on this one, really appreciating it.